# How to get two way databindings working in blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have got the following component which resembles a `TextBox` component. However for some reason the content of `Value` never seems to change.

I would have expected this to work with Data binding without manual JavaScript, no?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind="Value" @onkeyup="OnKeyUp" placeholder="@Placeholder"/>
</div>

@code {
    
    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Placeholder { get; set; }

    private void OnKeyUp(KeyboardEventArgs obj)
    {
        ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not bind to a `[Parameter]` as it can cause side effects ([see Steve Sanderson's comment here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24599#issuecomment-697588562) )

You appear to want two way binding on every change, for which I would use `oninput` rather than `onkeyup`, but you can use `onkeyup` if that is truly what you need.

The main thing to is to bind to a local and never change the public Parameter manually:

```cs
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
           @bind-value=@InternalValue 
           @bind-value:event="oninput" 
           placeholder="@Placeholder"/>
</div>

@code {

    string InternalValue
    {
        get => Value;
        set 
        {
            if (value!=Value)
            {
                ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);        
            }
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Placeholder { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: Adding Steve Sanderson's notes in case they disappear...

Quote from Steve Sanderson on the GitHub issue linked above:

> OK, I've looked in more detail and see what's going on. There's an
> explanation below, but before getting to that, I'll restate my claim
> that the core problem is the child component overwriting its own
> [Parameter] property value. By avoiding doing that, you can avoid this
> problem.
>
> In this instance, and in others, Blazor relies on parent-to-child
> parameter assignment being safe (not overwriting info you want to
> keep) and not having side-effects such as triggering more renders
> (because then you could be in an infinite loop). We should probably
> strengthen the guidance in docs not just to say "don't write to your
> own parameters" and expand it to caution against having side-effects
> in such property setters. Blazor's use of C# properties to represent
> the communication channel from parent to child components is pretty
> convenient for developers and looks good in source code, but the
> capacity for side-effects is problematic. We already have a
> compile-time analyzer that warns if you don't have the right
> accessibility modifiers on [Parameter] properties - maybe we should
> extend it to give warnings/errors if the parameter is anything other
> than a simple { get; set; } auto property.
>
> So in this case the solution is pretty simple: replace Component1's
> Value property with a simple { get; set; } one, and the instead of
> trying to write to it, have Component1 respond to button clicks by
> triggering ValueChanged. Then you don't have any recursive render
> cycle, and no data overwriting occurs.
>
> ```
> private void DecrementValue()
> {
>     //Value--; <-- Don't do this
>
>     // Do this instead:
>     ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value - 1);
> }
> ```

Comment: As of .NET 7, you will get a compiler warning BL0007 if component parameter is not auto property. The solution in this answer helped me getting rid of that warning since the InternalValue property is not a parameter.